# How to set multicast in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, configuration

The following `/etc/network/interfaces` file brings up the dummy0 interface automatically at startup (or using the `ifup` command), but without multicast. What is the proper way to enable multicast in this file?

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet static
   address 10.10.0.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   multicast 1

source-directory interfaces.d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet static
   address 10.10.0.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   post-up ifconfig dummy0 multicast
```